# iCloud setUbiquitous error "User Deleted Zone", how to recreate zone without CloudKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I've got an app that sets some files as ubiquitous using the NSFileManager setUbiquitous method. This is working great, the files are synced across multiple devices correctly.

The problem arises when the user manually deletes these files from the iCloud "Manage Storage" options in Settings. If they use the "Delete All" option, they can no longer upload any files to iCloud using our app. The setUbiquitous function returns TRUE with no error, but looking in the device log I see the error "User Deleted Zone" when it tries to upload the file.

After doing some searching I see other people mentioning this is a CloudKit error. I'm not using CloudKit at all - I simply call setUbiquitous to upload files, and use a query to find what files are available.

How do I recreate the deleted zone without using CloudKit? Is there a function that I'm supposed to be calling elsewhere that would normally recreate this zone for me?

If I do have to use CloudKit, a code snippet would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you get anywhere with it? I'll post whatever I find back here.

Comment: I actually ignored the error and released the app and haven't heard of anyone else having the problem. I wonder if it was something I created while coding in the iCloud support that doesn't happen to normal users? I'm really not sure.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering. I think I accidentally switched CloudKit support on at one point, before disabling it, and now it is behaving like a weird hybrid even though I just need and use `setUbiquitous` in the app. I'm searching, but there are precious few examples which give a clear answer, none so far with code. Unfortunately in my case, users are reporting something which looks the same, so I can't really ignore it. It does seem to be related to users deleting their store with Settings. I'll keep looking.